# How can I add contents of an external file to my Razor MVC3 layout file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my _Layout:

```
@if (ViewBag.PageFormat == "Footer Buttons")
{

}
```

If I pass the "Footer Buttons" string in the viewbag then I would like to insert CSS code from an external file directly into the cshtml file. Something like an insert of the contents of an external file right into the cshtml file between the { and }.

Is there a way I can do this with MVC3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean load up CSS from an external file as inline CSS code, you should create an extension method on your HtmlHelper.

```
public static class CssHelper
{
   public static MvcHtmlString LoadCss(this HtmlHelper html, string file)
   {
       string css = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(file));
       TagBuilder styleTag = new TagBuilder("style");
       styleTag.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
       styleTag.InnerHtml = css;

       return MvcHtmlString.Create(styleTag.ToString());
   }
}
```

which you can call in your code like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.PageFormat == "Footer Buttons")
{
   @Html.LoadCss("~/Content/mycss.css");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Actually I already have the CSS tags in my external file. Could I just simplify this by putting the System.IO.File.ReadAllText(html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(file); directly into my razor file?

Comment: You could, but it's bad design to do such things. Doing it this way will increase code reuse and separate complicated logic from your view to adhere to the MVC architecture.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with your suggestion. Just a quick question. Can you please explain what you mean when you say "you should create an extension method on your HtmlHelper". Can you explain where my HtmlHelper file is and how I should call this file. Thank you. Bev

Comment: An extension method lets you "extend" a class (even if it's not your own class) to add new methods to it. Notice in my example we can call `Html.LoadCss` even though the `LoadCss` method doesn't exist on the `HtmlHelper` class. We've defined an extension method on that class with the use of the static `CssHelper` class and providing a static method with the first parameter of the type we are extending preceded by the `this` keyword. You can read more about extension methods [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: The easiest way to call this is to just place that `CssHelper` class in the root of your MVC app. If you place it in some other folder or other namespace you may have to modify your web.config in your Views directory to include that in the imported namespaces which you can read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642.aspx).